# Rails Model Data Over Time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model that has data that can change monthly. I'd like to track that data over time so that we can pull up to the last 24 months worth (creating line graphs and such).

What's the best way to store that kind of data in a Rails model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a model that `belongs_to` the first table which stores the data and the time for that data.

When the value on the first model changes, you make a new row in the values table with the corresponding value and time.

Comment: Ohh that's cool. So essentially model one `has_many` of the second models which just record the data and the data/time of that data.

Comment: Yep, just watch out if you're running somewhere like Heroku that has a 10,000 line limit for the database on the free plan.